# Python search function not returning anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search for strings in a list to find and return the results of a user inputted search case insensitively when the user searches any part of the string, returning all items for which their search is present. But instead the output is nothing.

```
def search(movies):
    search_for = str(input("Enter search: "))
    searching = search_for.casefold()
    found = []
    for item in movies:
        if searching in item:
            found.append(item)
    return found
```

Why does the function not return anything, and how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Works fine here! Please check for any other issues.

Comment: Please show some sample input and output.

Comment: Can you include a sample of the input the function would take in (`movies`, I mean)? I see nothing wrong with the code assuming it's just a list with movie titles.